# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples [Sklearn and Time Series]

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series

I'm new with python and I'm trying to learn how to use Sklearn with my own data. I essentially just got the residual from my ARIMA Model and the approximation from my discrete wavelet transform and tryed to fit it to get a better model. But, I got this error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Guilherme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 330, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)

  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 902, in _validate_input
    multi_output=True)

  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 531, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])

**ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 974]**
```

This is how my inputs looks like:

```
residual [-0.62259993  6.71457698  8.14639867 ...,  3.17906001 -7.54454573
  4.38012835]
approximation [ 59.91585806  61.33864282  64.3283577  ...,  43.82833793  44.61630255
  46.4758499 ]


X [[ 59.91585806  61.33864282  64.3283577  ...,  43.82833793  44.61630255
   46.4758499 ]
 [ -0.62262456   6.71456765   8.14639445 ...,  -4.5462162   -7.28155588
  -18.45525218]]
```

and this my target:

```
Y [ -0.62274596   6.71452528   8.14634609 ...,  -4.54623634  -7.28158029
 -18.4552741 ]
```

Here is my code

```
    ## ANN
print('residual',len(residual))
A = A[4:978]
Residual = residual[0:974]
X = np.array([A,Residual])
print(X.shape)

y = np.array(residual[0:974])
print(y)


clf = MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=1e-05, batch_size='auto',
       beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False,
       epsilon=1e-08, hidden_layer_sizes=(15,), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=1, shuffle=True,
       solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=False,
       warm_start=False)

clf.fit(X, y)                        

print(clf.fit(X, y))
```

By the way, this is my references

> Khandelwal, I., Adhikari, R., Verma, G. (2015). Time Series Forecasting using Hybrid ARIMA and ANN Models based on DWT Decomposition. Procedia Computer Science 48 ( 2015 ) 173 – 179

[Neural network models (supervised)[1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html)

Comment: I am not able to understand your X. Please explain more. The error is due to mismatch in number of samples and number of targets.

Comment: According with  Skicit-learn's MLP.fit,  X would be like X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features). So I input the residual from ARIMA model as n_features and approximation (from discrete wavelet transform) as n_sample). Both of this variables has shape (974,). Likewise, Y has the same shape. I tryed transpose Y but nothing happened.